# OpenGL ES 2.0 iOS zero alpha pixel creating opaque color

Tags: ios, opengl-es, blending

I clear a framebuffer...

```
glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

...I enable blending as such...

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
[self render]
glDisable(GL_BLEND);
```

In that render code, I simply add a quad and draw it. In my fragment shader I have...

```
gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
```

This yields a clear quad. Great. No color, no alpha, no nothing...got it. However, I change the fragment shader to...

```
gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
```

I get the quad filled with white.  Can someone explain to me how filling a quad with fully transparent red would yield opaque white, and not just clear?

Comment: Are you using depth buffer / depth testing?

Comment: Well, you have `GL_ONE` as the first argument to `glBlendFunc()`. So you add the fragment color to the destination value, independent of the alpha value.

Comment: @RetoKoradi right so the fragment color is (1, 0, 0, 0), and the destination color is (0, 0, 0, 0).  Adding them together gives (1, 0, 0, 0), right?  Why is it that a final value of (1, 0, 0, 0) renders as white?  It seems to me it should be clear since the alpha value is 0, or at least some shade of red?

Comment: @AyanSengupta I have depth testing disabled actually.  Is that an issue?

Comment: Yeah, you'd think it would be red.

Comment: @RetoKoradi lol, right?  I feel like I'm taking crazy pills!  Thanks for looking, thought!

Answer (score 0):

doesn't GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA do

```
(1, 1, 1, 1) - (As/kA, As/kA, As/kA, As/kA)
```

so if As is 0 it will result in (1, 1, 1, 1)?

ED though I'm not clear why that has a different effect when you set your fragment to (1, 0, 0, 0) from (0, 0, 0, 0). I notice that I used

```
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)
```

What do you get with different arguments to the blend function?